# Cycle Combined bake only adds lighting on side of mesh

Tags: texture-baking

so when I try baking something using combined, it only works on the side of the mesh. What i mean is that my only light source is above my mesh, like so :

[image]

Yet the final result has zero reflection on the top parts, as you can see here [image]

Surface of object that the sun is lighting up:

[image]

And it's pretty easy to see the ring has zero reflection on it (Is mostly comprised of highly reflective metallic pieces)

What do I do? Mind I'm fairly new to baking on blender, so if possible please  be as concise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason, it was that since it was an empty scene it could only bake unto itself. The surface at the top was facing nothing, whilst the surface on the sides could reflect off of eachother.

That means if you want to have a light source also show up in a picture, that light source needs to be inside of some sort of object, such as a sphere or whatnot.